# how to create line chart using chart.js in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKE31.png)

this chart is basically display personal loan information.

I don't know how to make this chart using chart.js 
I am unable to give code because my code is not sufficient to represent this chart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna try to write down the whole process because somebody else already did it https://dev.to/wiaio/implementing-a-chartjs-line-chart-in-your-angular-application-19d7

Answer (score 0):

This is a line chart. Your data is an array with values like `[10000, 8000, 5000, 0]` for your y-axis and your labels are in an array with values like `[0, 15, 35, 60]`, representing the values for your x-axis with the y-axis-values.

For the `Rs.` you need label-callbacks, and you need special ticks and stepSizes for your scales to display all ticks like you want them.

I think you can find all information you need with googling the names I gave you. If you have more questions, ask them here. But be more specific, a simple "Do this for me" won't work here.

Comment: I have use maxTicksLimit to hide some ticks but how to show their labels.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Don't show ticks, but show their labels? That's strange. What do you need that `stepSize` can't do?